# JSON transform in Mule 3

Tags: json, mule, mule-studio

I have a JSON payload which looks like:

```
[{
  "CUSTOMERAP": [{
    "CUSTOMERID": [
      "7685940002,24424424,244322,1224,68"
    ]
  }, {
    "RATING": [
      "76859400022,24424424,244262,1234,68"
    ]
  }]
}, {
  "CLIENTAP": [{
    "CUSTOMERID": [
      "76859404002,24422424,246422,1254,68"
    ]
  }, {
    "RATING": [
      "76859400022,24422424,244522,1264,68"
    ]
  }]
}]
```

I would like to transform it to something like

```
[{
  "CUSTOMERAP": [{
    "ID": [
      "7685940002,24424424,244322,1224,68",
      "76859400022,24424424,244262,1234,68"
    ]
  }]
}, {
  "CLIENTAP": [{
    "ID": [
      "76859404002,24422424,246422,1254,68",
      "76859400022,24422424,244522,1264,68"
    ]
  }]
}]
```

I tried to iterate using foreach and was unable to obtain the titles separately using #[message.payload."title"] cause all of it are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in console of web browser . Create a var jsonData

```
var jsonData = [
{
    "CUSTOMERAP": [{
            "CUSTOMERID": [
                "7685940002,24424424,244322,1224,68"
            ]
        },
        {
            "RATING": [
                "76859400022,24424424,244262,1234,68"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "CLIENTAP": [{
            "CUSTOMERID": [
                "76859404002,24422424,246422,1254,68"
            ]
        },
        {
            "RATING": [
                "76859400022,24422424,244522,1264,68"

            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

By type this

```
jsonData[0].CUSTOMERAP[0].CUSTOMERID
```

you will get ["7685940002,24424424,244322,1224,68"] and so on apply a loop over get the index and get all values and make a new var jsonNewDataFormat 
and assign them as you want like

```
var jsonNewDataFormat = { Id : jsonData[0].CUSTOMERAP[0].CUSTOMERID }
```

if you hit this , you will get your data in new format try to apply Json. Stringfy ( google it)

```
jsonNewDataFormat[0].Id
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your [Expression transformer](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Expression+Transformer+Reference) look like? See also, [*How to transform or modify a JSON payload in Mule ??*](http://bushorn.com/json-to-json-transformation-in-mule/)

---

Alternatively, you could create a transformation function. This seems like it would not be very difficult.

```js
var data = [{
  "CUSTOMERAP": [{
    "CUSTOMERID": [
      "7685940002,24424424,244322,1224,68"
    ]
  }, {
    "RATING": [
      "76859400022,24424424,244262,1234,68"
    ]
  }]
}, {
  "CLIENTAP": [{
    "CUSTOMERID": [
      "76859404002,24422424,246422,1254,68"
    ]
  }, {
    "RATING": [
      "76859400022,24422424,244522,1264,68"
    ]
  }]
}];

function transformJson(jsonArr, groupingKey) {
  return jsonArr.map(itemOuter => {
    var wrapper = {}, grouping = {}, keyOuter = Object.keys(itemOuter)[0];
    grouping[groupingKey] = itemOuter[keyOuter].map(itemInner => {
      var keyInner = Object.keys(itemInner)[0];
      return itemInner[keyInner][0];
    });
    wrapper[keyOuter] = [grouping];
    return wrapper;
  });
}

console.log(transformJson(data, 'ID'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```